# How to pause and resume a thread without use threading logic inside it

Tags: c#, multithreading

i cannot put threading logic inside of Run method, the run method executes many operation in database.

like this:

```
void Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
         InsertEntitiesA();
         DeleteEntitiesA();
         UpdateEntitiesA();

         InsertEntitiesB();
         DeleteEntitiesB();
         UpdateEntitiesB();

         InsertEntitiesC();
         DeleteEntitiesC();
         UpdateEntitiesC();
     }
}
```

if i pause it and the thread is on DeleteEntitiesB() i want it to stop there, and then when i resume i want it to start from where it's been stopped, DeleteEntitiesB() on the line it's been stopped.

is there a way to perform it?

i dont think there is =(

Ps: Like i said the Run method cannot be modified

Comment: Use mutexes, Auto/ManuallyResetEvents, semaphores etc. but don't use Suspend or Resume.........

Comment: What if the code is inside DeleteEntitiesB at the time? Do you want to wait suspending it until it leaves that method? Please note that there is a reason I'm asking this question so I want you to carefully consider this question and decide whether you *don't care* if it does the above, if you *want* it to do the above, or if you *need* it to do the above. (do the above = wait until outside the method)

Comment: @EZI, I don't think that will help if OP can't edit the method.

Comment: will need to use things like : "wait_handle.WaitOne()" inside Run, i can't modify method Run

Comment: Why can you not modify the Run method?

Comment: Do any of these inner methods (Insert / Delete / Update) cause events to be fired? Can you modify these methods?

Comment: @AustinMullins he should, if needed . He should never use Suspend/Resume. There are many sites explaining why.....

Comment: If you can't change the Run method, can you change any of the methods it calls, or any of the code those methods call, etc.?

Comment: I can't modify nothing inside Run, not even the methods insert, del, upda..

Comment: If you tell us why you cannot modify the Run method there may be a work around that restriction.  Worse case, if it's a 3rd party library you don't have the code for, you could reverse engineer your own Run method that you can modify.

Comment: The code itself performs a synchronization between 2 databases, i'm stopping sql server service between synchronizations, i pause the synchronization  thread, then i start another thread that break sql connection (stopping the sql service) then when this thread ends, i must resume my synchronization from where it's been stopped, and i want to see it crashing, by reading a txt log where i write the erros.

in my test method, i start the synchronization , then i keep watch the log file, if nothing happens there is a error, if error happens that's ok, the error is the expected result.

Comment: i want to see if transaction scope will keep the base at the state it was when i started the transactions, it must rollback the changes it made

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Thread.Suspend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Thread.Resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.resume(v=vs.110).aspx) but it is generally a very bad idea. As you don't know where the thread is in its execution when you call these you have no idea whether it is in anything critical. If it is in something critical all sorts of havoc can ensue, this is probably why Microsoft decided to obsolete the methods.

Comment: i did this way, but my boss doesn't accepted this approach, ='(

Comment: i have no critical area, there is no concurrency, there is only this thread synchronizing step by step.

Comment: You would be surprised. It doesn't just break at the nice divide between methods in your code, it could be half way through a library function you called.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done without the thread's cooperation. What happens if you suspend the thread while it holds a critical lock? What if it holds a lock that the thread that is going to unsuspend it needs?